# fatal error C1189: #error: "Choose whether to link against shared or static."

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am trying to use the QtNodes Library (https://github.com/paceholder/nodeeditor) in my C++ Qt application. I built the library using cmake and then added QtNodes as a project to my solution. I also added the QtNodes project as a reference to my application project. Everything was going perfectly well until I tried including one of the files from QtNodes in one of the header files in my project.
Now when i try to build my application i get the following error: `...QtNodes\internal\Export.hpp(46,1): fatal error C1189: #error:  "Choose whether to link against shared or static."`
Here is a link to Export.hpp: https://github.com/paceholder/nodeeditor/blob/master/include/QtNodes/internal/Export.hpp.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define either `NODE_EDITOR_SHARED` or `NODE_EDITOR_STATIC` (`-DNODE_EDITOR_SHARED` or `-DNODE_EDITOR_STATIC`) in your project setting, of course depending on what Node Editor library you use.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you define this?
set(NODE_EDITOR_STATIC ON) in the QtNode Library CMakeLists.txt or my projects (where I will use the the library) CMakeLists.txt does not work.

Comment: I didn't add it to the CMakeLists.txt. I added it in the project settings in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

In "nodeeditor/include/QtNodes/internal/Export.hpp", it shows:

```
#if defined(NODE_EDITOR_SHARED) && !defined(NODE_EDITOR_STATIC)
#ifdef NODE_EDITOR_EXPORTS
#define NODE_EDITOR_PUBLIC NODE_EDITOR_EXPORT
#else
#define NODE_EDITOR_PUBLIC NODE_EDITOR_IMPORT
#endif
#define NODE_EDITOR_PRIVATE NODE_EDITOR_LOCAL
#elif !defined(NODE_EDITOR_SHARED) && defined(NODE_EDITOR_STATIC)
#define NODE_EDITOR_PUBLIC
#define NODE_EDITOR_PRIVATE
#elif defined(NODE_EDITOR_SHARED) && defined(NODE_EDITOR_STATIC)
#ifdef NODE_EDITOR_EXPORTS
#error "Cannot build as shared and static simultaneously."
#else
#error "Cannot link against shared and static simultaneously."
#endif
#else
#ifdef NODE_EDITOR_EXPORTS
#error "Choose whether to build as shared or static."
#else
#error "Choose whether to link against shared or static."
#endif
#endif
```

In "nodeeditor/CMakeLists.txt",you can find:

```
target_compile_definitions(QtNodes
  PUBLIC
    NODE_EDITOR_SHARED
  PRIVATE
    NODE_EDITOR_EXPORTS
    #NODE_DEBUG_DRAWING
    QT_NO_KEYWORDS
)
```

So, somehow the compile definitions does not work, you can add "NODE_EDITOR_SHARED" in compiler preprocessor.